# How can I know when two servers are ready to get requests?

Tags: go, go-gin

I have two servers

```
router := createServer()
loginServer := createLoginServerMock()
servLogin := &http.Server{
    Addr:         ":9333",
    Handler:      loginServer,
}
testServer := &http.Server{
    Addr:         ":9444",
    Handler:      router,
}
loginServer.ListenAndServe()
testServer.ListenAndServe()
```

And I want to send a request on both of them after they created? How can I detect that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ListenAndServe has no feedback mechanism to let you know when the server is ready. You have to create the listener yourself and pass it to [Server.Serve](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server.Serve):

```
loginListener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":9333")
if err != nil {
    // TODO: handle err
}

testListener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":9444")
if err != nil {
    // TODO: handle err
}

// You may already start sending requests now. They will just wait until
// the servers call Accept on their respective listener (i.e. shortly after
// Serve is called).

servLogin := &http.Server{Handler: loginServer}
testServer := &http.Server{Handler: router}

go func() { log.Fatal(servLogin.Serve(loginListener)) }()
go func() { log.Fatal(testServer.Serve(testListener)) }()
```

Answer (score 0):

`ListenAndServe()` will return an error when create server failed. Just handle it to known server start success or not. I can see your coding will only start login server while test server be hanging. Let's try

```
go func() {
  log.Fatal(loginServer.ListenAndServe())
}
log.Fatal(testServer.ListenAndServe())
```

Answer (score 0):

The program will wait at 1st `ListenAndServe()` until any error occurred. Because the `ListenAndServe()` method runs forever. So your second server will never started until the execution goes to the next `ListenAndServe()`. So use `go` in front of the 1st server's statement:

```
router := createServer()
loginServer := createLoginServerMock()
go func() {
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":9333", loginServer); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("login server err: ", err)
    }
}()
if err := http.ListenAndServe(":9444", router); err != nil {
    log.Fatal("test server err: ", err)
}
```

Then access your `loginServer` at http://localhost:9333 and `testServer` at http://localhost:9444.

Comment: Problem not in start, I wanna send request on two that servers and sometimes they not running both